# using python to parse through files for data

Tags: python-3.x, text, data-mining, text-parsing

I have two files one template file and one file which has the values for the template file. I am trying to take the template file and then pass values to the variables from another file and combine the two into a third file. I am able to copy one file to another using the following snippet of code
`

```
print("Enter the Name of Source File: ")
sFile = input()
print("Enter the Name of Target File: ")
tFile = input()
fileHandle = open(sFile, "r")
texts = fileHandle.readlines()
fileHandle.close()

fileHandle = open(tFile, "w")
for s in texts:
    fileHandle.write(s)
fileHandle.close()

print("\nFile Copied Successfully!")
```

`

however I am not sure how to do it for two or more files and then to make them into one file. Any help/guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the most elegant solution but I think it should work for you.

```
# You could add as many files to this list as you want.
list_of_files = []

count = 1
while True:

    print(f"Enter the Name of Source File{count} (Enter blank when done adding files): ")
    sFile = input()
    # If the input is not empty then add the filename to list_of_files.
    if sFile:
        list_of_files.append(sFile)
        count += 1
    else:
        break

print("Enter the Name of Target File: ")
tFile = input()

# With open will open the file and then close if when done.
with open(tFile, 'a+') as target:
    # This will loop over all the files in your list. 
    for file in list_of_files:
        tmp = open(file, 'r')
        target.write('\n' + tmp.read())
        tmp.close()
```